# QR algo for eigenvalue, eigenvector of $A_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to find the eigen value and eigenvector using QR algorithm of the following symmetric matrix

$$A_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I used the method described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/finding-matrix-eigenvectors-using-qr-decomposition#:%7E:text=The%20(basic)%20algorithm%20with%20QR,X%20by%20a%20symmetric%20matrix.&text=The%20matrices%20sequence%20Xn,of%20%E2%88%8FiQi.)

At first iteration the Q matrix comes out as
$$Q_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 & -0.5 \\
0.5 & 0.5 & -0.5 & 0.5 \\
0.5 & -0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
-0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

The R matrix comes out as
$$R_1=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2  \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

In the second iteration $A_2=R_1Q_1$ comes out as the same as $A_1$ and thus the iteration never converges.

Below is my code in Matlab I am not allowed to use any inbuilt function

```
function [evalue,evector] = qr(c)
    evalue = c;
    evector = eye(size(c));
    count =0;
    while true
        aprime = evalue;
        count = count +1;
        % normalising the first column of matrix
        normi =0;
        for i = 1:size(aprime,1)
            normi = normi+aprime(i,1)^2;
        end
        normi = normi ^ 0.5;
        for i = 1:size(aprime,1)
            aprime(i,1) = aprime(i,1)/normi;
        end
        % first column is normalised
        % calculating the orthogonal vectors by taking the dot product 
        for j =2:size(aprime,2)
            for k = j-1:-1:1
                temp = zeros(size(aprime,1));
                dotproduct = 0;
                for l = 1:size(aprime,1)
                    dotproduct = dotproduct + aprime(l,j)*aprime(l,k);
                end
                for l = 1:size(aprime,1)
                    temp(l) = dotproduct*aprime(l,k);
                end
                for l = 1:size(c,1)
                    aprime(l,j) = aprime(l,j)-temp(l);
                end
            end
            normi =0;
            for i = 1:size(c,1)
                normi = normi+aprime(i,j)^2;
            end
            normi = normi ^ 0.5;
            for i = 1:size(c,1)
                aprime(i,j) = aprime(i,j)/normi;
            end
        end
        evector = evector*aprime;            %qo stores the eigenvector matrix as multiplication of all q's
        rprime = aprime.'*evalue; %calculating the r matrix
        evalue = rprime*aprime;   % calculating iterative matrix
        if count > 100
            disp(evalue);
            break;
        end
    end
end
```

Why does the QR algorithm not work in this case? I tried with the example matrix used [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/finding-matrix-eigenvectors-using-qr-decomposition#:%7E:text=The%20(basic)%20algorithm%20with%20QR,X%20by%20a%20symmetric%20matrix.&text=The%20matrices%20sequence%20Xn,of%20%E2%88%8FiQi.) and it gave the correct output.

Comment: Your question will be difficult to answer, because it is based on two mysterious and apparently counterfactual assertions.  1) Your iterations converged.  You say so yourself! (2) Why do you believe this is not "correct output"??

Comment: Are you using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization method or Householder reflections method or anything else?

Comment: @ttnphns I am using gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation.

Comment: @whuber 1) it didn't converge for the matrix $A_1$ but I check for other matrices and it did converge. 2)I  verified it by putting it into eigenvalue problem equation $A v = \lambda v$

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are faced to a pathological matrix.

Here is what I have done in order to arrive at this conclusion :

First of all, I have computed the eigenvalues of matrix $A_1$. They are :

$$-2,2,2,2$$

Then, I have used the built-in "qr" routine of Matlab (that you say you aren't allowed to use) ; see program below). Applying it a certain number of steps, we see that, oddly

- Matrix $Q_k$ changes at each iteration by switching columns $C_1 \leftrightarrow C_2$ and $C_3 \leftrightarrow C_4$ (which means that $Q_{2k}=Q_{2k+2}$, $Q_{2k+1}=Q_{2k+3}$;
- Matrix $R_k$ becomes, past the second iteration, remains always equal to $D$=diag$(-2,-2,2,2)$, instead of becoming for example diag$(-2,2,2,2)$.

This infinite loop, testimonies a pathological behavior : whatever your program (and it seems it is correct), you will not succed.

Not a real surprise : it has been reported that the simple $QR$ algorithm may fail to converse. It is why it is usually implemented with a first transformation of the given matrix into a so-called "Hessenberg form" (+ other tricks like shifts). *Check that it works by un-commenting the 6th line in the program below*.

I think, without being able to prove it, that the fact that the given matrix has all its eigenvalues with the same absolute value is one of the main reasons for this convergence failure.
Matlab program :

> ```
> M=[1,1,1,-1
>    1,1,-1,1
>    1,-1,1,1
>   -1,1,1,1]
> eig(M), % eigenvalues are -2,2,2,2
> %[P,H]=hess(M);M=H
> [Q,R]=qr(M)
> for k=1:50
>    [Q,R]=qr(R*Q)
> end;
> ```

Comment: I just added the Hessenberg transform in the program, and it works !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried running your code but it still gives R as the diagonal matrix with elements with entry (-2,2,2,2) and hence is not converging and giving correct result.

Comment: I should have mentionned that $(-2,2,2,2)$ and its opposite $(2,-2,-2,-2)$ are considered as identical because you can transfer a minus sign from $Q$ to $R$ because $QR=(-Q)(-R)$

Comment: It doesn't help in finding out the eigenvectors. The product of Q's doesn't yield the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues. Should we go for an iterative method to find eigenvector corresponding to these eigenvalues or can QR method be further modified so that these eigenvectors is found.

Comment: Basic QR algorithm is made for obtaining eigen*values*. Nevertheless, you can also get eigen*vectors* with this Hessenberg form : see Algorithm 4.3 p.73 of this excellent [document](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/chapter4.pdf) (you will see that it's not evident).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will go through it.